# Spring-MVC - JSON ajax post to controller errors out

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, json, spring-mvc

**Relevant JS**:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType : 'json',
    url : "post",
    data : JSON.stringify(person),
    success : function() {

    },
    error : function() {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

**Relevant Controller Code:**

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping(value = "/post", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void posted(@RequestBody Person person) {
    System.out.println("Post");
    System.out.println(person.toString());
}
```

**Problem:**

After posting, the controller behaves like everything worked just fine.  My print statements fire and person.toString() produces expected results.  However, my ajax call fails, alerting an "Error", and I can't figure out why, because other than that, everything is working just fine.

I tried using Postman to post the JSON manually, and I'm getting a response of "415 Unsupported Media Type", and after some digging, I still don't know how to deal with this error so my success() function fires.  Any ideas?

Comment: Your whole method shouldn't be getting invoked. Can you show your Spring MVC config? What Spring version are you on?

Comment: Or rather you should be getting a 406, not a 415.

Comment: Removing the dataType attribute on my ajax call did fix it. Why are you saying that my whole method should not be invoked?  I'm on Spring 4.0.5

Comment: dataType expects a json response from server where as you are not responding with any response.

Comment: A 415 means the server is expecting content different than the one you are sending. It would fail before even creating the `Person` object it needs to pass to the method.

Comment: A 406 states that the content generated by the server is not acceptable to the client. That's what you should have gotten and would explain how removing `dataType` works.

Comment: It is completely possible that I was using Postman incorrectly, resulting in the strange response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dataType attribute of .ajax() function in jQuery is "The type of data that you're expecting back from the server."

You should remove it if you don't output json in your Controller.

For more info, see the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score -1):

remove this:

```
contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

because your content type is plain text from the begining:

```
System.out.println("Post");
```

That contentType will work only if the content is json.

Comment: Same with the dataType attribute i think.

Comment: The contentType attribute is required for Jackson to parse the JSON string to an object.  Removing it breaks my print statements

Comment: However, removing the dataType attribute did fix it, thanks @caRameL.

Comment: FYI according to the jQuery doc:  "any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected; the server should return a response of null or {} instead."

Comment: The content is json `JSON.stringify(person),`.

Comment: Thanks guys.  @caRameL, if you want to add your comment as an answer, I will accept it.